# why my odometry is moving around when use slam_gmapping

Tags: slam, lidar, ros-noetic, slam-gmapping, rplidar

[image]

```
<node pkg="differential_drive" type="diff_tf.py" name="diff_tf" output="screen">
</node>

<node pkg="rosserial_python" type="serial_node.py" name="serial_node">
<param name="port" value="/dev/ttyUSB0"/>
</node>

<node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find roper)/maps/projek.yaml"/>

<!--  ***** Navigation ******  -->
<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find roper)/cfg/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find roper)/cfg/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find roper)/cfg/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find roper)/cfg/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find roper)/cfg/dwa_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />

    <param name="base_local_planner" value="dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS" />
    <param name="controller_frequency" value="5.0" />
    <param name="controller_patience" value="15.0" />

    <param name="clearing_rotation_allowed" value="false" /> 
    <!-- Nox is able to rotate in place -->
</node>

<!-- tf agar map dan odom sama-->
<!--node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_to_odom" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 map odom 10"/-->

<!-- Load URDF file into parameter server -->
 <arg name="gui" default="True" />
  <param name="use_gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
  <param name="robot_description" command="cat $(find roper)/urdf/nox.urdf" />

<node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" />

  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" />

<!-- SLAM Gmapping-->
<node name="slam_gmapping" pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" output="screen"/>



 <!-- Add this line to launch rplidar_ros -->
<include file="$(find rplidar_ros)/launch/rplidar_a1.launch"/>





 <!-- AMCL -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are talking about the movement of the odom frame here. If the result from your global odometry (map frame) does not report the same change in motion as from your local odometry (odom frame), then the global odometry will "correct" this. This correction will result in a movement of the odom frame relative to map frame.

For example:
If your local odometry says you move 1m in x-direction, and global odometry says you move 1m in x-direction, then they will report the same and odom frame remains still. However, if global odom reports 0.9m, then there is a discrepancy of 0.1m. This will cause the odom frame to move.

In general, if local and global odom are agreeing with each other, then the odom frame will remain very still, whereas if the odom frame is moving a lot you will have less agreeing motion estimates.